# Set Power BI parameter from Yesterday to Today with Times

Tags: parameters, powerbi

I am importing data from a SQL database using query. There is a 'createDateTime' column in table that I am importing data from.  I want to import data into steps -

1. From yesterday 5:00:00 PM to today 5:00:00 AM on a daily basis
2. Perform incremental data refresh after import every hour from today 6:00:00 AM to Today 5:00:00 PM

While creating the RangeStart and RangeEnd parameters, I want to pass the DateTime values as in 1 and 2 above.

I tried using :
Date.ToText(Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-1), "yyyyMMdd")&& Time.FromText("17:00:00")

Not sure what the best way is of setting these parameters

Comment: You can think about 1 parameter Date. Every time you schedule the Import, take MAX(Date) from your destination database and select all from source database with condition source_db.Date > MAX(destination_db.Date).

Comment: You'll be limited to refreshing the dataset to 8 times a day, unless you have premium